# Jqgrid setting a select in Editform

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

Heres the deal, I have a JqGrid with a column("Status") with 3 possible numbers that I format(and unformat) to 3 different icons in the grid. But I need to format those numbers as a select type with a selected option when im in Edit mode.
Iv done that but the combo in Editform shows without any preloaded selection from the grid even if it has a value. Any row I select in the grid comes in EditForm with the same combo value.
But if I select any option in Editform and save it, it will update normally.
What am I missing?

**Colmodel definition of the status:**

```
colModel:[ 
    {name:'status_solicit_vale',index:'status_solicit_vale',width:120, align:'center', formatter:'iconFmatter', unformat:'iconUnFmatter',
            stype:'select', editable: true,  searchoptions:{value:":Todos;0:Aguardando;1:Autorizado;2:Rejeitado"}, edittype:"select", 
            editoptions:{value:"0:Aguardando;1:Autorizado;2:Rejeitado"} }
        ],
```

**EditOptions definition:**

```
{
        Modal:true,
        reloadAfterSubmit : true,
            recreateForm : true,
            closeAfterEdit : true,
        closeAfterAdd : true,
        reloadAfterSubmit: true,
        checkOnSubmit: true, 
        closeAfterEdit: true,
        bClose: "Fechar",
        saveData: "Confirma alteração?",
        bYes : "Sim",
        bNo : "Não",
        bExit : "Cancelar",
        afterSubmit: function () {
                jQuery("#gridJson").jqGrid('setGridParam',{datatype:'json'}).trigger('reloadGrid');
                return [true,'']; // no error
        }
}, // EDIT OPTIONS
```

**Format and unformat for the icons in the grid:**

```
iconFmatter : function(cellvalue, options, rowdata) {
    switch(cellvalue){

        case 0: var html = '<div class="ui-state-attention ui-corner-all" style="display:table"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" title="Aguardando" id=0></span></div>';
        break;
        case 1: var html = '<div class="ui-state-check ui-corner-all" style="display:table"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-check" title="Autorizado" id=1></span></div>';
        break;
        case 2: var html = '<div class="ui-state-error ui-corner-all" style="display:table"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-closethick" title="Rejeitado" id=2></span></div>';
        break;
        default: html = "ERRO";
        break;

     }
     return html;
    },      
    iconUnFmatter : function(cellvalue, options, cell) {    
        return $('span', cell).attr('id');
    }
```

[image: Jqgrid select]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved!**

Jqgrid wasn't unformatting the icon. 
I had to put my unformat function into the "colmodel" unformat property and it worked fine.